# Install v8js-0.1.3 with ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to install v8js-0.1.3 with Ansible, so I have the following task:

```
- name: Install pecl package
  pear: name=pecl/v8js-0.1.3 state=present
```

But this task freezes.

So I tried with ssh:

```
pecl install v8js-0.1.3
```

And it prompts me with a question (I think this is why it freezes):

```
Please provide the installation prefix of libv8 [autodetect] :
```

How can I tell Ansible to select the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`pear`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pear_module.html) module's [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/packaging/language/pear.py) it doesn't look like this is possible directly in the module.

One option would be to use [`expect`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) which is essentially shelling out but with the ability to interact with the response from the command.

So your task might look something like:

```
- name: Install pecl package
  expect:
    command: pecl install v8js-0.1.3
    responses:
      Please provide the installation prefix of libv8: "{{ libv8_install_prefix }}"
```